# make a string variable a command in Python

Tags: python, string

I want to make a string variable a command in Python for example:

```
p = "print('hello world')"

-p become to command
```

how can i do this? thank you

Comment: `eval(p)` .....

Comment: Don't do this. Dynamic code execution is almost *never* the solution you should use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p = "print('hello world')"
eval(p)
```

Sample test:

```
>>> eval(p)
hello world
```